# how to create 65 lags in SaS without copying and paste 65 times

Tags: sas

I got a panel data. `symbol` is my company names. `date` and `hour` represent the time. I want to create upto 65 lagged return variable. I can achieve this target using the following code. However, I have to copy and paste 65 times which is very messy. Can anyone tell me how can I improve the code please.

```
data data (drop=i count);
  set data;
  by SYMBOL DATE hour;
  array x(*) rlag1-rlag65;
  rlag1=lag1(return);
  rlag2=lag2(return);
  rlag3=lag3(return);
  rlag4=lag4(return);
  rlag5=lag5(return);
  rlag6=lag6(return);
  rlag7=lag7(return);
  rlag8=lag8(return);
  rlag9=lag9(return);
  rlag10=lag10(return);

  /* Reset COUNT at the start of each new BY-Group */
  if first.SYMBOL then count=1;

  do i=count to dim(x);
    x(i)=.;
  end;
  count + 1;
run;
```

I also want to run the following regression 65 times. Can you also teach me how to loop this regression and auto change the output file name please. Essentially, I want the lag of the independent variable should be the same as the last/last two digit of the name of the output file.

```
proc reg data=data noprint outest=lag1;
model return = rlag1;
by DATE hour;;;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Do you have a SAS ETS license?

Comment: I just checked using PROC SETINIT;RUN;     the following message shows up" ---SAS/ETS      31JUL2015" , so I guess I am licensed with ETS

Comment: Look at Autoreg procedure, otherwise I'm pretty sure you need a macro solution.

Comment: Can you write me a sample code please. It will be really helpful.

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/sas_macros_introduction/ the section on repeating procedures multiple times has exactly the code you need for regression repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to achieve this.

First get some sample data and sort it by the `by` varaibles we need:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.stocks out=have;
  by stock date;
run;
```

Now in a datastep, define the variables we are going to store the values in.  Also make sure we `retain` them so that they keep their values across observations.  We can achieve both of these things by using the `retain` statement.

Then define an array based on the variables we just defined in `retain`.  The array will allow us to refer to the variables lag1-lag10 without explicitly typing their exact names.

In my example, I want lags 1 to 10.  Note that I'm keeping another variable called `lag0` though - this is because it will help simplify the code.  We drop this variable at the end.

So the logic basically says, if it's the first observation for a stock, intialise all of the values in the array to missing.  Then assign the value of the current stock closing price to `lag0`.

If it's not the first of the stock, then starting at the maximum lag (in this case 10), assign it the value of the next-oldest lag (in this case 9).  Repeat this all the way through the array until we have done lag1=lag0;  Finally, assign the value of the current stock closing price to `lag0`.

This effectively shifts all the values down in the array as we go over the observations.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by stock;

  retain lag0-lag10;

  array a[0:10] lag0-lag10; 

  if first.stock then do;
    do cnt=0 to 10;
      a[cnt] = .;
    end;
  end;
  else do;
    do cnt=10 to 1 by -1;
      a[cnt] = a[cnt-1];
    end;
  end;

  a[0] = close;

  drop lag0 cnt;

run;
```

For your regression, you can loop over a piece of sas code as shown below.  I'll leave it as an exercise for you to adapt this to your code.

```
%macro reg;

  %do cnt=1 %to 10;

    data x&cnt;
      set want;
      value = lag&cnt;
    run;

  %end;

%mend;
%reg;
```